# Can a function whose domain is noncovex be a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Suppose I have a function $f:\text{dom}(f)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\text{dom}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, that obeys the convexity rule, i.e.,

$$
f(\theta\mathbf{x}+(1-\theta)\mathbf{y}) \leq \theta f(\mathbf{x}) + (1-\theta)f(\mathbf{y}),\;\forall\; \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \text{dom}(f), 0\leq\theta\leq 1
$$

However, consider further that $\text{dom}(f)$ happens to be a nonconvex set, e.g.,

[image]

- Is it possible to have such situation?
- If the previous question is yes, is $f$ a convex function?

Comment: No. From your "convexity rule" it implicitly follows that the domain of $f$ is convex.

Comment: You can define whatever you like, but the [usual defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) requires a convex domain.

Comment: @BrunoKrams that is right. The convexity rule already guarantees that $\text{dom}(f)$ si convex.